# Ошибка при компиляции проекта. C++

Tags: c++

Даны две матрицы А(nxn) и C(nxn). Написать программу вычисления матрицы Ст*(А+С), где Ст - транспонированная матрица.

Я вроде как написал код, но не могу написать транспонированную матрицу C, компилятор жалуется на не понятную мне ошибку, помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чём причина? Жалуется на строку №28

Ошибка: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0052194E в ConsoleApplication8.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00500000.

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int n = 3;
int main()
{
    int a[n][n];
    int c[n][n];
    int M[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> c[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < n; j++) {
            M[j][i] = c[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < n; j++) {
            cout << M[j][i] * (a[i][j] + c[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int j = 0; i < n; j++)` опечатка, и это не компилятор жалуется а запущенная программа валится

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, всё заработало!)